CSS Flexbox Layout with Nested Scrollable Section
I'm working on a layout using CSS Flexbox where I need to achieve a specific structure with a main container and nested children, each serving different parts of the UI. The main goal is to have a scrollable section within a nested child element, without causing the overall page layout to exceed the viewport height. Here's the structure I'm aiming for:

A main container with a height of 100vh.

A topbar with a fixed height of 80px.
A flex container (let's call it content-area) designed to take up the remaining space with flex-grow: 1.

Within content-area, an aside element that spans the full height of its parent.

The aside contains two children:

A div that should expand with flex-grow: 1 to fill the available space.
Another div with a fixed height of 140px.


Inside this expandable div, there's an h3 followed by a div with a class .filter-bar--scrollable-section. I want this div to occupy all available space and have a overflow-y to handle content that exceeds its remaining height.






A bottombar with a fixed height of 80px.



Here's a simplified version of my HTML structure:
<main class="main">
  <div class="topbar">Topbar Content</div>
  <div class="content-area">
    <aside>
      <div class="expandable-area">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div class="filter-bar--scrollable-section">
          <!-- Dynamic content here -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fixed-area" style="height: 140px;">
        Fixed Height Content
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
  <footer style="height: 80px;">Footer Content</footer>
</main>

And the CSS:
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content-area {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  height: 100%;
}

.expandable-area {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.filter-bar--scrollable-section {
  /* How should I style this? */
}

I've attempted to set flex-grow: 1 on the .expandable-area to make it fill the available space, and I want the .filter-bar--scrollable-section to fill the remaining space within .expandable-area and be scrollable if its content exceeds the space.
How can I style .filter-bar--scrollable-section to achieve this? I've tried various combinations of overflow-y and adjusting flex properties but can't seem to get it right. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

There will be other solutions, but when you know the exact height of the other areas, I'd probably just use calc to fix its height.
.expandable-area {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 300px);
}

.filter-bar--scrollable-section {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

